# how to convert english decimal to spanish decimal, using globalization in c#

Tags: c#, globalization

im using visual studio 2008. my desktop application runs in different regional settings.

in my code, i have decimal numbers in string variables in english format, i want to convert them to decimal variables using `Convert.ToDecimal()` with regional settings as "Spanish (Ecuador).

when i do the following:

```
string myNum = "0.04";  
decimal myDec = Convert.ToDecimal(myNum); // here im getting 4 instead of 0,04
```

when i used,

```
Convert.ToDecimal(myNum, new CultureInfo("en-US")); // i got 0.04, but i want 0,04
```

i cant add the new `CultureInfo("en-Us")` for every statement, coz i have used conversion statements more than 100 times.

how do i achieve this. please help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than creating a new culture each time, it would be better to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` - and I would personally use `decimal.Parse` or `decimal.TryParse` rather than `Convert.ToDecimal`. Just my personal preference though. IIRC they only really differ in terms of handling null input.

However, if you're just objecting to including that in your code each time, the simplest solution would be to write your own helper method and call *that*. For example:

```
public static decimal ParseDecimalInvariant(string text)
{
    return decimal.Parse(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

As an aside, I hope you don't *really* have the string values in your code. If you've got strings which represent numbers, just change them to literals instead!

```
decimal myNum = 0.04m;
```

That's much better than parsing at execution time :)

Comment: i followed your code. it is working fine, but when in some cases, with regional settings as "spanish (ecuador)", when i pass, decimal.Parse("10,50", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); im getting 1050. why is this so ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct answer here is going to involve code changes. You can change the app's culture, but IMO that is incorrect since it overrides the user's preferences for display etc.

Normally, you would throw the required culture the *code* uses into a static field somewhere, and pass that culture in for every bit of your code that interprets a *system* string literal. In your cases, since the code literals are in an english format, you can pass in `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` each time and save some effort.

Yes, it'll be 100 code changes; frankly: tough.